# Application Context loading the Beans that were removed in Project long back

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am working with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext of Spring.
 Developing my application on Intellij. 
 I have added models to my maven projects :
    compile, persistence, entity.db, ...

Later on i decided to get rid of persistence module, in which i created instituteDao.

 But now my ApplicationContext still loading beans defined in that module i.e. "instituteDao". 

 Problem 1: I am not sure how and where it has cached it.

 Problem 2: Have noticed delay in loading application Context, Is it related with current problem? 

 Tried restarting intellij, even restarted system. Still the same issue. 

 PFA screen shot, and let me know if more information is required. [image]

I have deleted instituteDao service. Don't have any class in my project to create a bean with instituteDao. 
PFA screen shot: [image]

Comment: can you share screenshot of instituteDao ?

Answer (score 1):

After a long day struggle. What i have found is my project module: entity.db.service.impl has defined dependency of persistence in pom.xml. 

 So, the application context is creating beans defined in that module as well.

Why my maven build was successful, because module jar files are there in my local repository. 

 So did all the clean up: clean up local repository and removed unwanted dependency from my project module to get it work.

Thanks all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean the project and build again.

Comment: Did it multiple times:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html